# How we can avoid this ERROR in Wso2ESB

Tags: wso2, wso2-data-services-server, wso2-esb

i am using Wso2ESb 4.7.0 latest version  and Wso2DSS 3.0.0 
its working fine some times clients sending parallel requests that time its giving some ERRORS and Warnings
like this

```
      SourceHandler I/O error (Probably the connection was closed by the remote party):Broken pipe
 WARN - SourceHandler Connection time out after request is read: http-incoming-2240
18,799]  WARN - SourceHandler Connection time out while writing the response: http-incoming-2156
[2013-08-14 17:10:19,801]  WARN - SourceHandler Connection time out while writing the response: http-incoming-2161
[2013-08-14 17:10:19,801]  WARN - SourceHandler Connection time out while writing the response: http-incoming-2171
[2013-08-14 17:10:19,802]  WARN - SourceHandler Connection time out while writing the response: http-incoming-2162
[2013-08-14 17:10:19,802]  WARN - SourceHandler Connection time out while writing the response: http-incoming-2178
[2013-08-14 17:10:19,802]  WARN - SourceHandler Connection time out while writing the response: http-incoming-2159
[2013-08-14 17:10:19,802]  WARN - SourceHandler Connection time out while writing the response: http-incoming-2173
[2013-08-14 17:10:19,803]  WARN - SourceHandler Connection time out while writing the response: http-incoming-2179
[2013-08-14 17:10:19,803]  WARN - SourceHandler Connection time out while writing the response: http-incoming-2174
[2013-08-14 17:13:50,157]  INFO - LogMediator To: http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous, WSAction: , SOAPAction: , MessageID: urn:uuid:b522b7bb-c01c-4b6c-a214-3cb00cb6c663, Direction: response, clientid =
```

In this case my application not working how we can avoid this 
for more scalability.Wso2esb not forwarding messages

Comment: Broken pipe exception occurs when connection is closed by one end..and that socket cannot be used after that..That is why ESB couldn't forward the message. What is you synapse configuration..?and what version of ESB you are using?

Comment: i mentioned my wso2esb version above any way i am using wso2 esb 4.7.0 .In this case my esb not working.What does it mean of synapse configuration will u explain about that

Comment: Synapse configuration =proxy services+sequences etc..

Comment: in which file i need to do this modifications

Comment: http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/ESB470/Synapse+Configuration+Reference in this they are saying we will let u know in next doc